# Using a binary search tree to implement a set of points

Tags: java, api, binary-search-tree

My assignment asks me to implement a point set API class using a binary search tree, using `java.util.TreeSet`. the PointSet API outline is shown below:

```
public class PointSET {
    public PointSET() {}                               // construct an empty set of points
    public boolean isEmpty() {}                        // is the set empty?
    public int size() {}                               // number of points in the set
    public void insert(Point2D p) {}                   // add the point p to the set (if it is not already in the set)
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {}              // does the set contain the point p?
    public Collection<Point2D> range(RectHV rect) {}   // all points in the set that are inside the rectangle
    public Point2D nearest(Point2D p) {}               // a nearest neighbor in the set to p; null if set is empty
}
```

- The `Point2` object is a simple point with x and y coordinates and a few other methods to calculate distances between two points.
- The `RectHV` object represents a rectangle used in a range search for points within the rectangle.

I guess I'm unsure of how to implement this API class in a BST. We've learned about BST's in class, but only in a broad sense; what they are and the postorder/preorder/inorder ways to search through them.

I'm also confused as to what an API is in and of itself. What makes this an API as opposed to something that is *not* an API?

**What does "implementing" the API involve?** and how do I use `java.util.TreeSet` to do it?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You would use the BST as your data structure to store all the points, instead of storing them in another structure, such as an array

Comment: A `TreeSet` *is* a binary search tree; internally it's implemented as a red-black tree. So it's not really clear how `TreeSet` is connected with implementing your own BST, but for details on how to use `TreeSet`, see [it's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of an application programming interface (API) as a contract. It specifies the way objects interact with each other.

In order to illustrate what an API is, consider the interface `Dictionary`:

```
public interface Dictionary {
    List<String> loadWords();
}
```

The interface `Dictionary` establish the contract (API) that all dictionary implementations have to follow. Two examples of dictionaries implementation could be:

```
public class TextFileDictionary implements Dictionary {
    public List<String> loadWords() {
        // load words from a text file and return them
        return words;
    }
}

public class DatabaseDictionary implements Dictionary {
    public List<String> loadWords() {
        // load words from database and return them
        return words;
    }
}
```

Let's take now your `PointSET` class as an example. As you can see, it has a bunch of methods that define the behavior of an object of the type `PointSET`.

```
public class PointSET {

    // private ... <- your data structure goes here.

    public PointSET() {}
    public boolean isEmpty() {}
    public int size() {}
    public void insert(Point2D p) {}
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {}
    public Collection<Point2D> range(RectHV rect) {}
    public Point2D nearest(Point2D p) {}
}
```

As @alexBrand pointed out, a good starting point is to define your data structure. In your case, the obvious choice is a BST. Then, in order to be coherent with the provided API, you are going to have to manipulate your data structure(s) to implement the expected behavior of `PointSET`.